# Automatically restart linux on hung task timeout dmesg

Tags: linux, php, reboot

I think I have a issue related to random networking issues, that affect and make my php processes to get stuck in D state.

This prints a kernel error:

```
[Tue May 17 11:24:55 2022] INFO: task php-fpm:3017789 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Tue May 17 11:24:55 2022]       Not tainted 4.15.0-176-generic #185-Ubuntu
[Tue May 17 11:24:55 2022] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

Is this considered a kernel panic that work [with automatic reboot after kernel panic](https://serverfault.com/questions/20006/automatic-reboot-after-kernel-panic)

If this doesn't work I was thinking in just creating a while loop checking for that error message in dmesg log, then reboot if found, but I think there's probably a safer and more elegant way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer on very good [blog by Jethro Carr](https://www.jethrocarr.com/2019/01/05/automatically-restarting-gnu-linux-hosts-upon-hung-storage/)

You just need to add to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
# Panic if a hung task was found
kernel.hung_task_panic=1

# Reboot 5 seconds after panic
kernel.panic=5
```

Just sharing because who knows how long that blog will be around, but if this is not allowed in this community I am sorry.